# Kotlin Not able to recognise Deferred/Promise/Future values in a map which has Values as String or Deferred Value

Tags: android, kotlin, promise, backend, future

```
val varToValue = mapOf("@id" to arg.userId, "@salary" to arg.salary)


            for (variable in varToValue.keys) {
                fieldData = fieldData.replace(Regex(variable),if(varToValue[variable] is String)  varToValue[variable] else varToValue[variable]?.await() ?: "") //here
            }
```

Here `fieldData` is a string which might contain `@id` or `@salary`. `arg.id` is of type String and `arg.salary` is of type `Deferred<String>`. Now the line where I call the replace function is not able to identify the `await()` call. It is giving me the suggestion of Rename reference. Basically I think it is not able to identify that it is of Deferred type. How do i solve this problem. I can make a different map for Deferred and normal type but I was hoping I could solve in one for loop and just one map.

Comment: It is not logically possible. A map returns items all of the same type. The compiler cannot be so sophisticated that it can figure out exactly what is in the map at any given spot in your code.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Can typeCast  when the value is not String to Deferred<String>.

Answer (score 0):

Can simply typecast the `varToValue[variable]` when it is not a `String`.

```
fieldData = fieldData.replace(Regex(variable),if(varToValue[variable] is String)  varToValue[variable] else (varToValue[variable] as Deferred<String>)?.await())
```

This seems to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Kotlin is a strongly typed language and a `Deferred<String>` and `String` are two different types. The easiest way to solve this problem would be to change them both to be `Deferred`, for example, wrap `arg.id` into a `CompletableDeferred`:

```kotlin
val varToValue = mapOf("@id" to CompletableDeferred(arg.userId), "@salary" to arg.salary)
```